# setprecision for boost::program_options

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

Is there a way to change how boost::program_options formats the default value of the options in the help text of a `program_options::options_description` (that one can obtains through `cout << description`)?  In particular I have default values which are floats, so the usual decimal-to-binary conversion gives me a help text that looks like `--arg (0.100000001)` which is quite ugly.

Using `cout << setprecision(4)` doesn't work because program_options is `<<`'ing itself the default values to some internal streams to do the formatting first (at least that's what I inferred by looking at the source code), and what gets `<<`'ed to `cout` is the resulting string(stream?).

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call [the two-argument version of `default_value`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/boost/program_options/typed_value.html#id1131772-bb). Then you can specify a string version of the value, and that will get printed instead of trying to print the given value with `<<`.